# How to get to Schiphol Airport at 5am using public transport from Amsterdam?

Tags: public-transport, airport-transfer, amsterdam, ams

How can you get to Schiphol using public transport at 5 a.m.? I understand public transport starts at 6 am.

I heard about some night buses but can't find their routes or which to take. I'm leaving from inside Amsterdam.

Comment: Just to be clear: 5am is the desired departure or arrival time?

Comment: There is a list of options to the airport [here](http://www.touristbuddy.org/), clicking on Bus 197 leads to [the company's site](https://www.connexxion.nl/dienstregeling/halte?id=57330224&lijn=M197&richting=2). You might want to explore them.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are hourly trains from Amsterdam Centraal station to Schiphol all night long, every day of the week.

Alternatively, http://9292.nl/en# is the public transport journey planner for Netherlands, which should have all the options.

Comment: From 20+ years ago, some of those trains also stopped at subsidiary stations (the closest to me was Muiderpoort, and there were a few trains that stopped there early in the morning on the way to Schipol).

Comment: The trains run 7 days a week, all year round with no more than a 7 hour break for New Years Eve. Sometimes the services have to be suspended for work or emergencies. In those cases the railways will have buses available.

Comment: Thanks @Willeke - I've replaced the "I'm not sure" based on this.

Answer (score 5):

I had this exact problem a couple months ago.  I got an Uber, costing €23.38.  There aren't a lot of Uber drivers at that time, but I saw four or five on the map, and I got picked up about 15 minutes after requesting one.  You might look into reserving one if you're nervous about availability.

Comment: FYI, [the Uber map (before requesting) is a complete and total lie](http://bgr.com/2015/07/28/uber-app-lying-cars-visual-effect/).

Comment: Ok, but I still had the nearest car head my way almost immediately.